# `cider-jack-in' aborts with 'Protocol family unavailable'

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

When I run `cider-jack-in` I get a `SocketException` with `Protocol family unavailable` as the exception message.

`lein repl` runs fine on the command line.

I've web-searched and found no matches containing both 'cider' and 'SocketException', which is always worrying. Nothing obvious came up in a search of the github project nor in the list of possibly-related questions presented here by StackOverflow as I'm writing this.

I get the same error whether I have a project file loaded or not.

My Emacs session tends to be extremely long-running (months) but I've checked and the problem still recurs identically after a restart.

Things I thought of that might be at play but I think I can discount:

- AFAIK no hosts on the subnet (this host among them) have IPv6 configured on any interface.
- This Emacs is running on the same host as a Squid proxy server, but `(getenv "no_proxy")` returns a comma-delimited string that includes both `localhost` and `127.0.0.0/16`, so no connection to the proxy server should be requested as part of connecting to an `nrepl` server on the same host.
- This host has a heavily customized `/etc/hosts` file, but no IPv6 address mappings are enabled.

In other words it should be a "pure" IPv4 host.

`emacs-version`: 24.5.1

`cider-version`: 0.15.1-snapshot

OS: Linux this-host 4.8.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.11-1 (2016-12-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Stack trace header:

`error in process sentinel: nrepl-server-sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable, compiling:(/tmp/form-init7765774181037314573.clj:1:73)`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt that cider knows or cares whether your system is purely ipv4; it still
seems to default to attempting use ipv6, shown in cider's startup messaging as
`lein ... repl ... :host ::` (the `::` being ipv6 equivalent notation
to localhost).  For my
situation, it was simple enough to just enable ipv6 on my system, but you
could instead follow [suggestions in this
issue](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues/1960) to set
`cider-lein-parameters` to `repl :headless :host localhost`.